# Google scope to list users in domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-workspace

I've been using the [users.list method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) to get a list of all users in a domain. The docs say, we need **one** of theses scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

With try & error I found that (at least for me) it is only working with these (all!):

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user

Do I have missed something? Or am I in the wrong context?

Answer (score 0):

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.domain` is probably used by something else in your code.   User.list only needs `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user`

Imo the likely culprit would be your authorization code. If you check [Directory API: Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing) you will see it says

[image]

Which may mean that in order to authorize a user you need that scope.  Which would be unrelated to the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user` scope used for the list method.